# Make folium heatmap change colors of areas based on a fixed number density

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I have latitude and longitude coordinates in the form required for adding a heatmap to a folium map. I wish to make two heatmaps (representing traffic density) on different instances of maps and compare the colors to judge the relative congestion of points. However, there is no discernible difference in the coloring scheme of the two heatmaps - the more "congested" heatmap doesn't look more red or darker than the less congested heatmap.

I tried passing the radius of each point separately to achieve this effect, in the following way:

```
radii = len(heatmap_list_)*[7] # for testing - make a list of radii.

for point, radius in zip(heatmap_list_, radii):

    HeatMap([point], radius = radius).add_to(map_hooray)

# Save the map
map_hooray.save("heatmap_short.html")
```

When I tried displaying the heatmap html file in a browser (tried Chrome and Edge), it takes forever to load and just ends up freezing even with a small number of x,y points. The file size also grows rapidly if I add heatmaps in a loop (as shown in the code), and after a certain file size the html file doesn't even load.

Is there a way to make this method work? If not, how can I achieve the effect of making the two heatmaps look different as they should based on number density of points? I guess somehow fixing/hard-coding the number density <-> color relation would address this issue but I haven't found a way to do this in Folium yet.

Comment: What's the min and max of the scale that is being used to map values (and breaks) to colors? Maybe `folium` scales and normalizes values prior to colorization?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is making a heat map each time you're executing the loop. Make one heat map where your input your datapoint as a list with weights [lat, long, wt].